# Ti Alloy, SearchView not filtering TableView for Android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am having issues on Android trying to get a `SearchView` to filter the results of my `TableView`. For iOS I am using a `Ti.UI.SearchBar` and the filtering works fine. On Android I am using a `Ti.UI.Android.SearchView` and the results don't seem to filter when I start typing.

---

My XML for the `TableView` and `SearchView` is

```
<TableView id="slideList">
    <SearchView ns="Ti.UI.Android" id="searchBar" iconifiedByDefault="false" />
</TableView>
```

In my controller I generate the `TableView` data through a loop and create a widget which is simply a `TableViewRow` with some custom props (specifically a prop called `searchFilter`).

```
function parseData(slides)
{
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
  {
    var row = Alloy.createWidget('com.dop.vforummobile.sliderow');
    row.init(slides[i], i);
    $.slideList.appendRow(row.getView());
  }
  $.slideList.search = $.searchBar; //-- Tie the SearchView to the TableView
  $.slideList.filterAttribute = 'searchFilter'; //-- searchFilter prop on my widget
}
```

My Widget (this shows I am setting a `searchFilter` property on the row):

```
var init = function(data, index)
{
  $.title.text = (index + 1) + '. '  + data.title;
  $.slideRow.startTime = data.startTime;
  $.slideRow.searchFilter = data.title + ' ' + data.slideText;
};
exports.init = init;
```

I have verified that `data.title` and `data.slideText` do contain text.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @Swanand I believe `searchFilter` isn't available to Android so I used `title` which would search based off the title prop of the row

Comment: @ Ronnie thanks... it working using title.